# Xampp and Sublime do recognize my php. I can't figure out why

Tags: php, validation

In sublime there is no syntax coloring, xampp ouputs it as plain text, and the php validator I used only comes up with $arr is not a variable.... I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
˂?php
    $arr = array(
        'properties' => array(
            array(
                'property' => 'email',
                'value' => 'apitest@hubspot.com'
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'firstname',
                'value' => 'hubspot'
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'lastname',
                'value' => 'user'
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'phone',
                'value' => '555-1212'
            )
        )
    );
    $post_json = json_encode($arr);
    $hapikey = readline("/");
    $endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact?hapikey=' . $hapikey;
    $ch = @curl_init();
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = @curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_errors = curl_error($ch);
    @curl_close($ch);
    echo "curl Errors: " . $curl_errors;
    echo "\nStatus code: " . $status_code;
    echo "\nResponse: " . $response;
?>
```

I have had and used this same installation of xampp for over a year, I have built many wordpress templates using this installation of sublime, All of a sudden this is happening. am I missing something?

It was happening with another piece of code in the same file that I swapped out with the above but I didn't notice. I have created three different files with the above code and they are all behaving this way. no errors just the code as text.

Comment: Maybe it has no extension or "double" extension?

Comment: It must be a charactor encoding issue. I just retyped all of the code in Sublime and I got syntax highlighting and xampp recognizes it as php now. I don't see any visible difference.